Scheduled task stays in execution
I have a scheduled task that sends a GMail with a subject, a body, and a file in it using an app called mailsend.-go.
This mail is sent using a script and the task executes every day at 7:00 AM.
When the task executes by itself at 7:00 AM or I do it manually, it stays in execution, and it doesn't work.
Here are the settings:



I tried to change some settings like adding arguments to the settings, and changing user settings.
I don't know if I'm forgetting something, but I need this, and I've been trying for days.
Here's the script:
# Directory containing Excel files
$directoryPath = "C:\Board\Dataset\Venda Diaria ASA\davidRibas.csv"

# Email address from which to send
$emailFrom = "no***@gb****.com"

# Email address to which it is sent
$emailTo = "da*****@ho*****.com"

# Mail subject
$subject = "Board - prova enviament venda diaria"

# Mail message
$messageToSend = "Cos del missatge - Us fem arribar una prova de l'enviament del fitxer de venda diaria"

# User
$user = "bo****@gb****.local"

# Password
$password = "*******"

# Comanda que s'executa per enviar el mail
mailsend-go -sub $subject -smtp smtp.gbassols.com -port 587 auth -user $user -pass $password -from $emailFrom -to $emailTo body -msg $messageToSend attach -file $directoryPath


Why did you tag [tag:powershell]? (There is no PowerShell anywhere in your question  )

This is likely because your script produces an error but you not sharing any script details. My general advice is to put some logging in your script (or use Start-TransScript which might help you where it fails (long shot: Windows Fast Logon Optimization feature, where the network might not even be up and running)

Does the recipient(s) receive the email or not? Share the code if you want better qualified advise :)

It only works when I execute the script manually, but not when the task is executed, I put the code in the question, sorry for not putting it before

powershell -file script.ps1

Afaik, you cannot run PowerShell scripts like this from Task Scheduler like they are defined to run with group policy startup or login scripts. You have to run it per "Program to start" as full explicit path all the way to and including powershell.exe (run where powershell.exe) and then use parameters accordingly to call the PS1 file. Might have to bypass execution policy if that's applicable and also add exit to bottom line of the PS1 script. Oh, also for Start in, put in path only where powershell.exe resides. I've written about this on many answers on SuperUser.

The solution is just writing the path of "powershell.exe" in the program you want to execute and writing -command "pathOfTheScript"

